# programmatically extract rows and columns from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame ex.

```
temp = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4),b=c(6,7,8,9),c=c(10,11,12,13))
> temp
a b  c
1 1 6 10
2 2 7 11
3 3 8 12
4 4 9 13
```

I want to extract the 2nd and 4th row of column "a" and "c", means:

```
a c
2 11
4  13
```

This "a" and "c" can vary during the input and can have more column names, so I put them into a list like,

```
t <- c("a","c")
output <- c(output,temp[2,t])
output <- c(output,temp[4,t])
```

But it returned me

```
> f
$a
[1] 2

$c
[1] 11

$a
[1] 4

$c
[1] 13
```

What I want is

```
a c
2 11
4  13
```

Comment: `temp[c(2, 4), c(1, 3)]` is what you want.  And using `c` is not a list; in my experience it means you've made a vector.

Comment: Or, instead of indexes for the columns, `temp[c(2, 4), c("a", "c")]`.

Comment: The exmple I gave is just for understanding. In real, there would be column names and the index position would be known during run time. So, I believe, I would need some other solution

Comment: I got it,,,Ananda Mahto, ur solution would work for me. Thanks.I can collect all the indexes in a list and in the end, can extract all the values.

Comment: FWIW, never use `t` as a variable name since it's actually a built-in function (transpose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered by Ananda Mahto in a comment to my question, I can store the rows and column names in vectors and use those to get the data I want:

```
> i <- c(2,4)
> ee <- c("a","c")
> temp[i, ee]
  a  c
2 2 11
4 4 13
```

Comment: `i` and `ee` are **not** lists. Please read up on data structures in R.

Comment: Do be sure to also mark your answer as "accepted" to help keep the "unanswered" queue clean.

Comment: I would..but I cant for next 20hrs